# Limiting distribution of $X_n1(|X_n|\le 1-\frac{1}{n})+n1(|X_n|>1-\frac{1}{n})$ if $X_n\sim Unif(-1,1)$ and are iid.

Tags: statistics, characteristic-functions

Limiting distribution of $X_n1(|X_n|\le 1-\frac{1}{n})+n1(|X_n|>1-\frac{1}{n})$ if $X_n\sim Unif(-1,1)$ and are iid.

From looking at the term, if $n$ goes to infinity, then $Y_n$ would be $X_n$ so it should have the same distribution as $X_n$.

$\displaystyle\psi_{Y_n}(t)=E[e^{itY_n}]=E[e^{itX_n1(|X_n\le 1-\frac{1}{n})}]E[e^{itn1(|X_n|>1-\frac{1}{n})}]=\left(\int_{-1+1/n}^{1-1/n}e^{itx}\frac{1}{2}dx\right)\left(\int_{-1}^{-1+1/n}e^{itn}\frac{1}{2}dx+\int_{1-1/n}^1\frac{1}{2}e^{itn}dx\right)=\frac{\exp{(it(1-\frac{1}{n}+n))}+\exp(-it(1-\frac{1}{n}-n)}{2itn}$

So I get $Y_n\sim Unif(1-\frac{1}{n}-n, 1-\frac{1}{n}+n)$

My problem is as $n\rightarrow\infty$, this characteristic function doesn't converge, instead it diverges to infinity.

Comment: why do you get $E[e^{itX_{n}1(|X_{n}|\le 1-\frac{1}{n})}] = \int_{-1+1/n}^{1-1/n}e^{itx}\frac{1}{2}dx$ ?

Comment: The pdf of $X_n$ is $\frac{1}{2}1(-1\le x\le 1)$ and since $X_n$ ranges from $-(1-\frac{1}{n})$ to $1-\frac{1}{n}$, I get the above. Is that not right?

Comment: $X_n$ ranges from -1 to 1, and when $|X_n| \ge 1- \frac{1}{n}$,   $e^{it X_n 1(|X_n|\le 1-\frac{1}{n})} = 1$ because $1(|X_n|\le 1-\frac{1}{n}) = 0$, if i'm not wrong. I got more terms, but the limit is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean 
$$Y_n=X_n1(|X_n|\le 1-\tfrac{1}{n})+n1(|X_n|>1-\tfrac{1}{n}),$$ one certainly does not get that $Y_n\sim\mathrm{Unif}(1-\frac{1}{n}-n, 1-\frac{1}{n}+n)$. Rather, your own computations yield
$$
\psi_{Y_n}(t)=\frac1t\sin(a_nt)+\frac1n\mathrm e^{\mathrm itn},\qquad a_n=1-\frac1n.
$$
When $n\to\infty$, $a_n\to1$ and $\frac1n\to0$, hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\psi_{Y_n}(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=\psi_Y(t),
$$
where $Y\sim\mathrm{Unif}(-1,1)$ and the conclusion follows.

As was to be expected, the independence property is irrelevant.

**Edit:** More direct arguments exist (but the one above follows yours as much as possible). For example, consider some random variable $X\sim\mathrm{Unif}(-1,1)$, then $Y_n$ coincides in distribution with
$$
Z_n=X1(|X|\le 1-\tfrac{1}{n})+n1(|X|>1-\tfrac{1}{n}).
$$
Since $Z_n\to X$ almost surely, $Z_n\to X$ in distribution, hence $Y_n\to X$ in distribution.

Comment: Thank you! I got it, how can I use a more direct argument? I tried by CDF but got stuck after $P(X_n1(|X_n|\le 1-1/n)+n1(|X_n|>1-1/n)<y)$

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: For the edit, do I have to show $Z_n\rightarrow X$ a.s. using the  Borel-Cantelli lemma?

Comment: No, just try to picture the sequence $(Z_n(\omega))$ for each fixed $\omega$ and you should see the almost sure convergence emerging quite clearly.